# modprobe: FATAL: Module uswhid not found in directory /lib/modules/5.0.0-23-generic

Tags: 18.04, mouse, lenovo

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module uswhid not found in directory /lib/modules/5.0.0-23-generic
```

I am using a Lenovo IdeaPad 330 with Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

My mouse was working, but today it is not working. I restarted my laptop, but the mouse is still not working. I am using a USB Microsoft mouse. It is still working on Windows, but now not in Ubuntu.

Comment: are you sure, you don't mean modul `usbhid` ?

Comment: when I search for the solution someone give to run some comment that include modprobe and i don't know what is meant by him and you

Answer (score 0):

usbhid is a modul for usb mouse. `modinfo usbhid`  give you a short overview. `lsmod | grep usbhid` show you if the modul is loaded or not.

If not `sudo modprobe usbhid`